# How to compare two HashMap<String, List<String>> with list items as values to check if value in hMap1 is present in hMap2

Tags: java, xml, hashmap

I have two separate maps with List of items as values. I'm reading data from two separate xml files to populate these maps.
The contents of the maps look like this:

```
    Map<String,List<String>> hMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String,List<String>> hMap2 = new HashMap<>();

    hmAP1   key:Bob val[aa,bb,cc,dd,ee]
            key:Sam val[ss,tt,uu,vv,ww]

    hMap2   key:Dan val[xx,pp,yy,qq,zz]
            key:Bob val[cc,dd,hh,kk,mm]
```

I want to compare the values in hMap1 and hMap2. In this case Bob in hMap1 [cc, dd] has values that are similar to Bob in hMap2 [cc, dd]. 
How do I add Bob and matching values only to new hMap3. I can't seem to get my head around, please.
Here's how far I've gone with reading the xml files and adding to hashMaps:

```
 public static Map<String,List<String>> checkSimilarValues (File file) throws TransformerException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException
    {

        Map<String, List<String>> hMap = new HashMap<>();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc1 = dBuilder.parse(file);
       // System.out.println(file.getName());
        doc1.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc1.getElementsByTagName("class");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                // list of include methods
                NodeList includeMethods = eElement.getElementsByTagName("include");

                for (int count = 0; count < includeMethods.getLength(); count++) {
                    Node node1 = includeMethods.item(count);

                    if (node1.getNodeType() == node1.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element methods = (Element) node1;

                        List<String> current = 
                      hMap.get(eElement.getAttribute("name"));

                       // List<String> current2 = 
                      map.get(eElement.getAttribute("name"));
                        if (current == null) {
                            current = new ArrayList<String>();
                            hMap.put(eElement.getAttribute("name"), current);
                        }
                       if (!(current.contains(methods.getAttribute("name")))) {
                            current.add(methods.getAttribute("name"));

                        }

                    }
                } 
            }

        }
        return hMap; 

    }

     public static void main (String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, TransformerException
    {
        File f1 = new File("sample1.xml");
        File f2 = new File("sample2.xml");

        Map<String, List<String>> hMap1 = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, List<String>> hMap2 = new HashMap<>();

        hMap1 = checkSimilarValues(f1);
        hMap2 = checkSimilarValues(f2);

        for (String key : hMap1.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key);

            for (String string : hMap1.get(key)) {
                System.out.println(string);

            }
        }

    }
```

sample1.xml

```
<classes>
<class name="Bob">
    <methods>
        <include name="cc" />
        <include name="cc" />
        <include name="hh" />
        <include name="kk" />
        <include name="mm" />
    </methods>
</class>
<class name="Dan">
    <methods>
        <include name="xx" />
        <include name="pp" />
        <include name="yy" />
        <include name="qq" />
        <include name="zz" />
    </methods>
</class>
```

sample2.xml

```
<classes>
<class name="Bob">
    <methods>
        <include name="aa" />
        <include name="bb" />
        <include name="cc" />
        <include name="dd" />
        <include name="ee" />
    </methods>
</class>
<class name="Sam">
    <methods>
        <include name="ss" />
        <include name="tt" />
        <include name="uu" />
        <include name="vv" />
        <include name="ww" />
    </methods>
</class>
```

Comment: You can first start with a brute force approach.

Comment: Implement a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: You can use reverse lookup where instead of class as key, use method as key

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to do this at the XML level using XSLT (2.0 or higher) rather than doing it at the Java level. For example you can create a document that merges the two inputs supplied using

```
<xsl:variable name="inputs" select="doc('sample1.xml'), doc('sample2.xml')"/>

<xsl:template name="main">
  <classes>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$inputs//class" group-by="@name">
      <methods>
        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(current-group()/methods/include/@name">
          <include name="{.}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </methods>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </classes>
</xsl:template>
```

This gives you the union of all the "include" elements for each name - I'm not sure if that's quite what you're asking for. It would be easier if you gave a high-level description of the problem you are trying to solve, rather than expressing it in terms of manipulations of Java hash tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
for (String k: hMap1.keySet()) {
  if (!hMap2.containsKey(k)) continue;
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(hMap1.get(k));
  list.retainAll(hMap2.get(k));
  resultMap.put(k, list);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort in helping out. This works very fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy in Java 8. You could stream both maps entries, filter entries whose key belongs to both maps and collect these entries to a new map, merging the values by intersecting them. In code:

```
Map<String, List<String>> hMap3 = Stream.of(hMap1, hMap2)
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .filter(e -> hMap1.containsKey(e.getKey()) && hMap2.containsKey(e.getKey()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
             Map.Entry::getKey,
             e -> new ArrayList<>(e.getValue()),
             (l1, l2) -> { l1.retainAll(l2); return l1; }));
```

---

Another possibility would be to iterate over `hMap1` keys and if `hMap2` contains the current key, put an entry into the new map that maps the key to the intersection of the values:

```
Map<String, List<String>> hMap3 = new HashMap<>();
hMap1.forEach((k1, v1) -> {
    List<String> v2 = hMap2.get(k1);
    if (v2 != null) {
        List<String> v3 = new ArrayList<>(v1);
        v3.retainAll(v2);
        hMap3.put(k1, v3);
    }
});
```

---

A variant that first copies data and then removes the differences:

```
Map<String, List<String>> hMap3 = new HashMap<>(hMap1);
hMap3.keys().retainAll(hMap2.keys());
hMap3.replaceAll((k, v) -> {
    List<String> v3 = new ArrayList<>(v);
    v3.retainAll(hMap2.get(k));
    return v3;
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Federico. It works fine in Java 8.